# Getting basic output of .exe file when running with Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, shell, git-bash

I am running a simple `test.exe` file I created. When I run it from *Git-Bash* I get this expected error:

```
$./test.exe 
C:/Users/userpian/Desktop/ABC/ConsoleApplication1.exe: error while loading shared libraries: ?: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

But when I run it from *Powershell*, I get nothing

```
$./test.exe
$
```

How can I get this error message from *Powershell*? I tried different approaches like using `System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo` but it hasn't helped me so far.

Comment: How does the executable return the error? Does it write to `stderr`? Some code would be in order, so [edit] that part in the question.

Comment: Judging from your first error, it looks like test.exe is trying to launch ConsoleApplication1.exe?  Is it possible that your PowerShell environment is not yet setup to locate test.exe; or that test.exe cannot locate ConsoleApplication1.exe; or the PowerShell user context cannot navigate into the C:\Users\userpian folder?  What happens in PowerShell if you just try to run `& "C:\Users\userpian\Desktop\ABC\ConsoleApplication1.exe"`?   BTW, your PowerShell example above looks like a Bash prompt.